# Notepad++ Portable: Session and Theme are Lost After Opening the App in \App\Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, portable-apps

I put my Notepad++ in my USB drive. The location is F:\Programs\Notepad++ Portable.

I was figuring a way to install plugin for the portable version, and I found the F:\Programs\Notepad++ Portable\App\Notepad++. I tried putting the plugin in the \plugins\ folder.

I accidentally opened the app in that directory (instead of opening it from the root), and when it opened, it just looks like a freshly installed Notepad++. I lost my session, and so is my theme (my theme cannot be read anymore).

The new plugin is present though (said plugin is Compare plugin).

Is there a way to recover the session and theme?

Notepad++ version is 7.5.4.

Comment: Did you download the portable zipfile directly from notepad-plus-plus.org, or did you trust a distributor like portableapps.com to bundle it as a portable for you?

Comment: Also, running it from "that directory" rather than from "root": what "root" do you mean?  If you go back to "root", does it go back to having your session/theme/settings?  On your F: drive, how many copies of `notepad++.exe` are there, and where exactly are they located?  What does **? > Debug Info** say for each of the locations to run it from?